# Adobe Acrobat Pro: anything similar to query-string or command-line arguments when 'invoking' the PDF?

Tags: javascript, soap, adobe, pdf-generation, acrobat

I am in the very early stages of finding a tool that can create "intelligent" dynamic PDFs on a web server, with a particular kind of desired intelligence:  when the PDF is "invoked" (opened, launched) it reads command-line arguments that are then used by the javascript embedded in the PDF to make SOAP calls.  Some pseudo-code to clarify:

```
// web-server pseudo code
ACROBAT acrobat = new ACROBAT();
acrobat.Open(PDFName, args[]);

// pseudo-code running inside the PDF enviroment

function MakeSOAPCall()
{
    custid = thisPDF.GetCommandLineArguments("CustomerID");  // extracts a value from args[]
    // now build a SOAP call using custid as one of the parameters
    .
    .
    .
}
```

Is it possible to do that with Acrobat Pro?

Comment: Even if it is possible, I suggest you study the Acrobat EULA. IIRC they don't allow network access to it. They will happily sell you their PDF library, though.

Comment: @Martin Schroeder: they're all in Arabic! http://www.adobe.com/products/eulas/pdfs/Acrobat10_combined-20100625_1456.pdf